# Any examples of actually using (not training) pre-training BERT models for NER?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'd like to use one of pre-trained BERT models to extract NER tags from sentences.  I can't seem to find any examples of doing so.  Every link I find on the web is about re-training models.  I just want to use them.  Basically, given a sentence such as "John Smith from Texas", I want tags such as ["PERSON","PERSON","GEO"].  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like [THIS](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert/)